# How to prevent accidental publishing of a private pub package

Tags: dart, flutter, dart-pub

When I have a package that I absolutely won't publish to pub.dartlang.org, how can I prevent someone accidentally publishing it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

add

```
publish_to: none
```

to your `pubspec.yaml`.

This setting can be used to specify a custom pub package server to publish to and `none` prevents publishing.